# Library to create Schematic maps (ie; Tube, metro maps) in flash

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, mapping, flash-builder

I have a project that requires me to create interactive schematic maps for rail networks. Something along the lines of London's tube map (Not the tube map itself. Are there any flash libraries out there that can assist with this sort of thing?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Why do you need libraries for something that's essentially static?  Why not just draw it in Flash CS?  I guess you could make it data driven, but seems like way too much work for what it's worth.  How often does a train map changes?

Comment: Can you please share the link to the final project or more information about the task?
Just wondering how could the data be aligned on the tube map

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for helpful drawing libraries? Data Visualization libraries?

this site/blog is great and he's got a few classes (CubicBezier..)
http://www.cartogrammar.com/blog

Farmcode.org has a open-source library that is great for tons of reasons, and they've made a 'fast 2D bezier' class.

Grant Skinner and Quasimondo have both released invaluable open-source stuff.

hope these help!